# Using sed to replace numbers

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'd like to replace some numbers in a file with the result of a calculation using the found number, and like to use sed on MacOSX. I've tried a lot of variants and now know I have to use -E to use modern instead of basic regular expression.

Some examples:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed s/\ +\ wwv_flow_id.offset/blabla/
```

gives

```
bla 18934750blabla bla
```

So without the -E, it finds and replaces fixed text.
But with the -E, it doesn't:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E s/\ +\ wwv_flow_id.offset/blabla/
```

gives

```
bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla
```

In other words: no match and no change in the text.
The ultimate goal is to find the number that precedes the fixed text " + wwv_flow_id.offset" and use that number and subtract a fixed number (say 750) from it, so the end result becomes:

```
bla 18934000 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla
```

And for that I need at least back references, which also don't work like I expected, because

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E s/\([0-9]+\)\ /\1/
```

gives

```
bla 1+ wwv_flow_id.offset bla
```

I hope some regex guru can help me out here.



**UPDATE**

With the help of ruakh, this is what I've got now:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+) \+ wwv_flow_id.offset/(\1-750) \+ wwv_flow_id.offset/'
```

which returns:

```
bla (18934750-750) + wwv_flow_id.offset bla
```

The bonus question now is, how to turn this into

```
bla 18934000 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla
```

**UPDATE 2**

I managed to achieve my desired result by combining sed with awk, like this:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)([ ]*)\+([ ]*)wwv_flow_id.offset/~\1~\2\+\3wwv_flow_id.offset/' | awk -F~ '{print $1 $2-750 $3}'
```

(I know for sure there are no `~` tokens on the original line)

Comment: Note that extended regexes use `()` for grouping and not `\(\)`. Remember to quote your sed script to protect it from shell expansion. `awk` would be much easier to use here.

Comment: Rob, I don't think sed is the best choice here. You want to match certain patterns and do arithmetic on some fields. For this better tools like awk and perl are available. It helps a lot if the file has some fixed format.

Comment: Thanks ruakh, ik_zelf and Chuck Kollars for all your help. I've posted a second update with the end result using awk as well. There'll likely be an easier solution, but I'm happy with this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In "modern" regexes, `+` has a special meaning — it means "one or more" (just like how `*` means "zero or more") — so to match an actual plus sign, you need to use `\+`. Since you apparently prefer not to wrap your `sed`-script in quotes, you would write it as `\\+`:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E s/\ \\+\ wwv_flow_id.offset/blabla/
```

though I think it will make your life easier if you abandon that preference, and write:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E 's/ \+ wwv_flow_id.offset/blabla/'
```

Quoting your argument will also address your back-reference issue, whereby Bash is translating `\1` to `1`:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+) /\1/'
```

though if you still prefer to stick with your non-quoted-`sed`-script style, you could write `\\1`:

```
echo "bla 18934750 + wwv_flow_id.offset bla" | sed -E s/\([0-9]+\)\ /\\1/
```

Comment: Thanks very much ruakh. This solves the two problems. Any ideas for the bonus question (see the update)?

Comment: @RobvanWijk: `sed` doesn't know arithmetic, only string manipulation. In your example, you've changed a trailing `750` to a trailing `000`; you could certainly achieve that with `sed`. But the general case of subtracting 750 is decidedly nontrivial, and you're better off using something like `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: Me too... The regular expression behavior of evaluating an expression and using the result [either (?{...}) or the modifier (lowercase) 'e'] is rather arcane and is _not_ supported by most RE processors, including `sed` (not even the "modern" version). Many Linux systems already have a `psed` so you can do sed-like things except really with PERL REs under the covers.  (Otherwise if you need to do arithmetic inside the RE, I recommend you explicitly stick to PERL.)